# JSF 2.0 Accessing a session scoped bean from within a view scoped bean

Tags: jsf, session, managed-bean

My application uses siteminder authentication. The siteminder will append user details such as username, userid etc to the http request header and redirect to my application. I need to store these user details from the header in a bean and access it in my business logic. Have a few questions.

1. What kind of scope is recommended for the UserDetailsBean ? Session or request ?
2. Where can I intercept the request and extract the user information from the header ? Can I do it inside a filter ? Or can I do it inside my UserDetailsBean (session bean)constructor ?

Can I do something like

```
public UserBean() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    Map<String, String> requestHeaderMap = context.getExternalContext().getRequestHeaderMap();

    String userId = requestHeaderMap.get("sm_userID");

        public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
public void setUserId(String userId) {
    logger.info("[Bean - User is] "+userId);
    this.userId = userId;
}
        }
```

And access the UserBean.getUserId throughout my application ?

Comment: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/7031941#7031941 2) Just try it and report problems you didn't understand, there this site is for. In the future, please post separate questions in separate questions.

Comment: From the post, I understand we can use sessionscoped bean. But I am not able to understand where exactly can I intercept my request headers containing user info? Can I do it within the session scoped bean itself or do I need a separate request scoped bean for that ? I am confused here because the info appears in "request" header, but the info contains user details which need to be a part of the "session"